# Which grid system to use for work in all devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3.2.
I got this information:

Small grid (≥768px) = .col-sm-*

Medium grid (≥992px) = .col-md-*

Large grid (≥1200px) = .col-lg-*

My question is I have to develop a website which should work on all platforms then which grid system should I use.

Comment: To answer your question: **ALL OF THEM** :)

Comment: You don't always need to use the medium/large utilities. It's as the design demands.

Answer (score 2):

```
.col-xs-$   Extra Small     Phones Less than 768px
.col-sm-$   Small Devices   Tablets 768px and Up
.col-md-$   Medium Devices  Desktops 992px and Up
.col-lg-$   Large Devices   Large Desktops 1200px and Up
```

Well we can have everything to choose with but prefer small grid.

Comment: How about customize sizes?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are misunderstanding the way the Bootstrap Grid system works. The utilities you see define the breakpoints to which anything under, if not defined, will take up the entire width of the grid.

Bootstrap is based on 12 columns (natively, but you can override that value with variables). There is size (xs, sm, md, lg and their breakpoints are referenced by @Pterpatty) and how many columns they consume (1 through 12). If you took @Wazan's answer into account,

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-8">Content Goes Here</div>
```

Your content would take up 8 columns at large, 6 columns at small and medium (since medium wasn't defined, but small was, it reverts down to that size), and 12 columns at extra small (phone size).

Because of the way Bootstrap works and is natively a mobile-first system, even if you were to define all your content in large alone, it would still "work" on phones, you would just have everything revert to the width of the device and stack underneath each other (if you had two div's side-by-side, the right would move under the left).

Comment: And furthering the discussion, please do read the proper protocols in constructing the [layout](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) and [head](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

Answer (score 1):

You can use it as

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-8">Content Goes Here</div>
```

[For More Detail](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use like this:

```
  <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
              Content
          </div>
   </div>
```

Inside the `row` you should use `col`

`xs` - extra small screen
`sm` - small screen
`md` - medium screen
`lg` - large screen